# Events depending on a dynamic variable at jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm wondering which would be the proper way to deal with events which depend on the status of a variable.

Right now, I have a listener which it is only added if the option `isTablet` is set to true. (as if not, it breaks in old versions of IE). So it looks like this:

```
if(options.isTablet){
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
      ....
    });
}
```

Now, I'm having troubles if I want to change the variable `isTablet` dynamically with a setter and It won't load the event `touchmove`.

```
$.fn.myPlugin.setIsTablet = function(value){
    options.isTablet = value;
}
```

I guess the simple way is always adding the event and inside it deciding whether or not to execute the code:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
    if(options.isTablet){
        ....
    }
});
```

But throws an error in IE 8:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

What would be the way of doing it?
Thanks.

Comment: You're probably right to always add the listener and check the condition inside. To avoid the error, since you're already using jQuery, just use jQuery: `$(document).on('touchmove', function(e) { ... });`

Comment: In other cases, for example `.scroll()` does it make sense to be checking a variable on every scroll? Isn't there any other way then? Thanks!

Comment: An alternative would be to use `on()` and `off()` to add and remove the handlers in your `setIsTablet` function

Comment: Which one do you think it would be better?

Comment: I guess it depends on how often the handler is called, and how long it takes the handler to run. For something like the scroll event, which is called very often, it might be better to remove the handler. For a click event, it's probably ok to check the condition.

Comment: Ok thanks. If you add it as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I would always add the listener and check the condition inside. To avoid your error, since you're using jQuery, just use jQuery:

```
$(document).on('touchmove', function(e){
    if(options.isTablet){
        ....
    }
});
```

If you have a handler that is called very often, you could consider turning it off when not needed. Something like this:

```
function myHandler(e) { ... }

$.fn.myPlugin.setIsTablet = function(value){
    options.isTablet = value;
    if (value) {
        $(document).off('touchmove').on('touchmove', myHandler);
    } else {
        $(document).off('touchmove');
    }
}
```

Be careful not to bind the handler more than once (like if `true` is sent to `setIsTablet` more than once in a row). You could also use a flag instead of unbinding/binding like I've shown.

Comment: You mean, using the `off` before the `on`, right? That's how you are doing it in the example. That way you will bind it only once right?

Comment: Yes, that should handle it. A flag might be more performant though.